# Tomcat SSL Cert Renewal Issue (SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, https

Attemping to renew a certificate that expired earlier this month and I can't seem to get it to work.

- Apache Tomcat 7.0.34
- Centos
- Java 1.7.0_65
- (Root Cert) I've tried Both  **gdroot-g2_cross.crt (Java Root)** And **gdroot-g2.crt** seperately and neither worked
- (intermed Cert) **gdig2.crt**
- (tomcat Cert) **The one I was given by GoDaddy**
- All newly SHA2
- [Instructions Used](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5239/generating-a-csr-and-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat-4-x5-x6-x7-x)

Step by step what I have done

1. Generate CSR using the already existing keystore via :
   `keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file csr.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore`
2. Submit the new CSR to GoDaddy
3. Receive Certificates from GoDaddy
4. Unzip them to my desired directory
5. Delete the old certificates from the keystore via :
   `keytool -delete -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore`
   (This was done with intermed and tomcat as well)
6. Add the new certificates to the keystore via:
   `keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file newrootfile.crt` (Again I did this with intermed and tomcat)
7. Check the `server.xml` (It is still pointed to the right keystore because I reused one)
8. Restart Tomcat
9. No errors in catalina.out, no errors when importing certs.
10. Attempt to bring up page gets Secure Connection Failed: FireFox(SSL_Error_no_cypher_overlap), Chrome (ERR_SSL_Version_Or_Cypher_Mismatch)
11. Spend the last five days trying different things

    - Creating new keystore instead of using old one
      -No errors again, but instead of Secure Connection Failed I get Unable to connect
    - Using different root certs from the GoDaddy Repository
12. Found out how to use openssl to check a connection

(Server is a virtual machine that has saved states so when I break it I can go back to when it was working)
With old SHA1 (expired):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myhost:443

CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
...
...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
.....
.....
----
No client certificate CA names sent
----
SSL handshake has read 4586 bytes and written 461 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
server public key is 2048 bit
....
SSL-Session:
   Protocol : TLSv1.2
   Cipher : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
   ....
   Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
---
closed
```

With new SHA2:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myhost:443

CONNECTED(00000003)
140219291584328:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:741
---
no peer certificate available
--
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 263 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation is NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

server.xml

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" "SSLEngine="on" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="path/to/users" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" />
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
   maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
   sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="path/to/keystore" 
   keystorePass="mykeystorepass" compression="on" />
```

Everything was previously set up by a developer before I began work here years ago, so I assume that he set up the server.xml correctly because it has been working for the past two years.

Any thoughts on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god I feel a fool, I thought when creating the keystore when it asks for a password for tomcat it wanted my tomcat manager password, nope just keep it the same as your keystore.

Also, **gdroot-g2.crt** is the correct crt needed for the root alias, you can get it from their repository.

Go daddy gives you a bundle for some reason.

Man such a stupid mistake.